# SAX PARSER IS NOT PASRSING AFTER "&" SYMBOL

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde, saxparser

my requirement is to parse xml data from the server side and display it in Blackberry, I am using SAX parser to perform this operation. I am using an example to explain the scenario.

`<Name>ABC</Name>
<Company>TCS</Company>
<Name>DEF</Name>
<Company>E&Y</Company>`

In the above example, it is possible to read all the attribute except the "E&Y".

Comment: could you post your code? I'm not exactly sure how SAX works on Blackberry but I think I had a similar problem.

Comment: @Mav3ric: thanks for your reply..I am not sure which code you are asking for XML or Java code?

Comment: Your java code of the xml handler/parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml is corrupted. Check for [xml escaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping).

Proper xml should look like:

```
<Company>E&amp;Y</Company>
```

Fix your xml and the parser becomes to work OK.

Comment: thanks for your reply..that was just a sample XML I posted there not the actual one..It is working fine for other XML Data from the server..Only the data with & symbol in it is not displayed on the BB client side ..

Comment: Sorry to say this, but then you are going to get not the actual answers.. Post the exact xml you get from the server on which your parser fails. Can you confirm it is properly escaped?

Comment: @Arihmed: thanks for your reply, I have figured out, yes you where correct..the xml reply I am getting from the server is this <Company>E&Y</Company>.. so I replaced the & with &amp; that solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread
[Blackberry UTF-8 Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125424/blackberry-utf-8-problem)

One ansewr says:

> Most likely your xml is in UTF-8 while you have `response.getBytes()`. String.getBytes() returns bytes for default OS encoding which is ISO-8859-1 on BB. So try to get UTF-8 bytes by calling `response.getBytes("UTF-8")`.

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

I guess the problem is the encoding

Search for "encoding='UTF-8' sax parser"

Comment: I don't know why the downvote but I would be glad to have some feedback.

Comment: thanks for your reply juanmabaiu, I dnt give a down vote for your reply.I wish the member who gave it would get back to you..